# Multiple monitors on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, desktop

I have Ubuntu 8.04.1 and two monitors. Both monitors are showing identical images. How do I fix it so that each of them shows its own desktop?

Comment: Video card information would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

*How to Set up Multiple Monitors in Ubuntu*

http://www.ehow.com/how_6300191_set-up-multiple-monitors-ubuntu.html